# Could the transition matrix on wiki be interpreted with "Rainy and Sunny" example?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, machine-learning

The [forward–backward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward%E2%80%93backward_algorithm) algorithm is an inference algorithm for hidden Markov models which computes the posterior marginals of all hidden state variables given a sequence of observations/emissions

The transition matrix is

$\mathbf {T} ={\begin{pmatrix}0.7&0.3\\0.3&0.7\end{pmatrix}}$

in the context of '[Rainy' and 'Sunny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model)', could the transition matrix be viewed as follow?

$T_{11} = 0.7, T_{12} = 0.3$ means the day after a `Sunny day` has a 70% chance of being `Sunny day` (staying), and a 30% chance of being `Rainy` (transitioning),

while $T_{21} = 0.7, T_{22} = 0.3$ means the day after a `Rainy day` has a 30% chance of being `Rainy day` (staying), and a 70% chance of being `Sunny` (transitioning).

is my understanding right?

Comment: I don't know lots of the terminology of the first paragraph, but everything after that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

When using the vector-matrix multiplication $\pi_{n+1}= \pi_n\mathbf T$, then $\mathbf T_{xy}$ is the *conditional probability* of it being $y$ on the next day when given that it is $x$ the 'current' day; and we are valuing $x,y$ as `1` for *rainy* and `2` for *sunny* ($x$ is the row, $y$ the column).

$$\begin{bmatrix}\mathsf P(W_{n+1}{=}r),\mathsf P(W_{n+1}{=}s)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathsf P(W_{n}{=}r),\mathsf P(W_{n}{=}s)\end{bmatrix}~\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}\mathsf P(W_{n+1}{=}r\mid W_n{=}r)&\mathsf P(W_{n+1}{=}s\mid W_n{=}r)\\\mathsf P(W_{n+1}{=}r\mid W_n{=}s)&\mathsf P(W_{n+1}{=}s\mid W_n{=}s)\end{bmatrix}}_{\bf T}$$

- $T_{11}$ is the probability that a *rainy* day follows a *rainy* day
- $T_{12}$ is the probability that a *sunny* day follows a *rainy* day
- $T_{21}$ is the probability that a *rainy* day follows a *sunny* day
- $T_{22}$ is the probability that a *sunny* day follows a *sunny* day

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this part $\begin{bmatrix}\mathsf P(W_{n}{=}r),\mathsf P(W_{n}{=}s)\end{bmatrix}$ represent the initial state $\pi$?

Comment: Yes.  The vector $\pi_n$ contains the probabilities that the weather on day $n$ has the indicated value (rainy or sunny, respectively).